# why i can not install the npm stripe checkout?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, stripe-payments

I am using: npm install vue-stripe-checkout, but a i get this error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined
at Function.Vue.use (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5106)
at eval (main.js?56d7:5)
at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1148)
```

in my main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import VueStripeCheckout from 'vue-stripe-checkout';

Vue.use(VueStripeCheckout, "pk_test_wk9TFDEeu4kRrI1pT0WxYrBC00bSQO9djj");

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: @tmhao2005, will be usefull to have a comment, and learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using the newest version of `vue-stripe-checkout` which has breaking changes that doesn't allow you to use as above way (as a plugin)

It currently exports 2 components: `StripeCheckout` and `StripeElements` which requires you to use them as component instead.

Here is a very basic example:

```js
<template>
  <stripe-checkout
    ref="checkoutRef"
    :pk="publishableKey"
    :items="items"
    :successUrl="successUrl"
    :cancelUrl="cancelUrl"
  >
    <template slot="checkout-button">
      <button @click="checkout">Check out</button>
    </template>
  </stripe-checkout>
</template>
 
<script>
import { StripeCheckout } from 'vue-stripe-checkout';
export default {
  components: {
    StripeCheckout
  },
  data: () => ({
    loading: false,
    publishableKey: 'YourKey',
    items: [
      {
        sku: 'sku_FdQKocNoVzznpJ', 
        quantity: 1
      }
    ],
    successUrl: 'your-success-url',
    cancelUrl: 'your-cancel-url',
  }),
  methods: {
    checkout () {
      this.$refs.checkoutRef.redirectToCheckout();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You could reference to here to see all examples for both components: https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout